# how to send data object and file image from angularJs to nodeJS

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, jax-rs

I'm looking for how to retrieve information from a form (text fields and image) sent from then angularJS to nodeJS.

-Html code:

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
<input type="text"  ng-model="UserName" required="required">
<input type="text"  ng-model="FirstName" required="required">
<input type="file"  ng-model="Image" required="required">
<button type="submit" ng-click="addUser()">save</button>
</form>
```

- Angular.js file:

> ```
> $scope.addUser=function(){
>       var user ={
>             UserName: $scope.UserName,
>            FirstName:$scope.FirstName
>                   };
>                 console.log("info User: "+user.UserName);//Well recovered data
>
>               $http.get(url+"/add",$scope.user,$scope.Image)
>               .success(function(data){
>                       $scope.ListUsers=data;
>               }).error(function(err,data){
>                   console.log("error " +err);
>               }); 
>            };
> ```

- Node.js file:

> ```
>     app.get("/add",function (req,res) {  console.log("data of user: "+req.body); //undefined
>  http.get(url+"/AddRest",req.body,req.Image, function (repsHttp) {
>  //error here
>                          var body='';
>                           repsHttp.on('data',function(d) {
>                               body += d;
>                           });
>                           repsHttp.on('end',function() {
>                               try {
>                                   var user = JSON.parse(body);
>                               } catch(e) {
>                                   console.log('error ', +body);
>                               }
>                               res.json(user);
>                           });
>                       });
>                   });
> ```

-API JAX-RS for the addition of a user:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Users AddUser( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile fileDetail, 
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody(required=false) Users user){

            UM.AddDataUsers(uploadedInputStream,fileDetail,user);
                        }
```

thank you for helping me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first.Angular’s ng-model doesn’t work on inputs with `type=“file”`so we need to create our own directive to bind files to variables in the view controller.

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

variable in the scope accordingly. This is achieved using the $parse service to set the value in our scope. The markup required in the view for the directive to work is simple

`<input type="file" file-model="Image"  required>`

When you are sending a image to server need to send it as `multipart/form-data` format. Since you need to send json with an image you need to append json object `formData` and send it.It should be post request also. can't send data using get requests

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.user = {
        UserName: $scope.UserName,
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName
    };
    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($scope.Image, function(file) {
        fd.append('file', file);
    });
    fd.append('user', JSON.stringify($scope.user));
    $http.post(url + "/add", fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': undefined
            }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.ListUsers = data;
        }).error(function(err, data) {
            console.log("error " + err);
        });
}
```

Also change the node method to post

```
app.post("/add", function(req, res) {
    console.log("data of user: " + req.body);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction it helped me a lot. But how to recover the User object and file?  ` console.log("data of user: " + req.body.user);//data of user: undefined`,

Comment: Someone could help me,